# Yii Multiple dropdownlist

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am newbie to yii. I am trying to create two dependent dropdownlist with one dropdownlist value. Here If I click region_id dropdownlist, it should updated cityname and cityname1 dropdownlist at the same time. I don't know how to write code for multiple ajax call. Below I have paste the code what I have tried.

```
<?php
echo CHtml::dropDownList('region_id','',
array(2=>'New England',1=>'Middle Atlantic',3=>'East North Central'),
array(
'prompt'=>'Select Region',
'ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST',
'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('site/loadcities'),
'data'=>array('region_id'=>'js:this.value'),
'success'=>'function(html)
{
jQuery("‪#‎city_name‬").html(html)
}' ,
array(
'type'=>'POST',
'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('site/loadcities1'),
'data'=>array('region_id'=>'js:this.value'),
'success'=>'function(html)
{
jQuery("‪#‎city_name1‬").html(html)
}' )
)));
echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_name','', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select City'));
echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_name1','', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select City'));
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write the other ajax request yourself. In fact, I prefer to store JS logic separate from view files, if it's practical (there's more than a few lines of code).

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('region_id','',
    array(2=>'New England',1=>'Middle Atlantic',3=>'East North Central'),
    array(
        'prompt'=>'Select Region',
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('site/loadcities'),
            'data'=>array('region_id'=>'js:this.value'),
            'success'=>'function(html)
        {
            jQuery(\'#‎city_name‬\').html(html)
        }' ,
                )));

echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_name','', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select City'));
echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_name1','', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select City'));

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('regionChange', '
    jQuery("#region_id").change(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "' . Yii::app()->createUrl('site/loadcities1') . '",
            type: "POST",
            data: {region_id: this.value},
            success: function(html) {
                jQuery("#city_name1").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
');
```